# How to group by multiple keys in spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a bunch of tuples which are in form of composite keys and values. For example,

```
tfile.collect() = [(('id1','pd1','t1'),5.0), 
     (('id2','pd2','t2'),6.0),
     (('id1','pd1','t2'),7.5),
     (('id1','pd1','t3'),8.1)  ]
```

I want to perform sql like operations on this collection, where I can aggregate the information based on id[1..n] or pd[1..n] . I want to implement using the vanilla pyspark apis and not using SQLContext.
In my current implementation I am reading from a bunch of files and merging the RDD.

```
def readfile():
    fr = range(6,23)
    tfile = sc.union([sc.textFile(basepath+str(f)+".txt")
                        .map(lambda view: set_feature(view,f)) 
                        .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
                        for f in fr])
    return tfile
```

I intend to create an aggregated array as a value. For example,

```
agg_tfile = [((id1,pd1),[5.0,7.5,8.1])]
```

where 5.0,7.5,8.1 represent [t1,t2,t3] . I am currently, achieving the same by vanilla python code using dictionaries. It works fine for smaller data sets. But I worry as this may not scale for larger data sets. Is there an efficient way achieving the same using pyspark apis ?

Comment: Instead of using `union` it's more efficient to load all the files with a since `wholeTextFiles` call (if it exists in PySpark).

Comment: Here's a Scala [aggregate reduction by multiple keys](http://dmtolpeko.com/2015/02/12/multi-column-key-and-value-reduce-a-tuple-in-spark/) and a Python [union reduction of multiple values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895033/spark-use-reducebykey-instead-of-groupbykey-and-mapbyvalues)

Answer (score 14):

My guess is that you want to transpose the data according to multiple fields.

A simple way is to concatenate the target fields that you will group by, and make it a key in a paired RDD. For example:

```
lines = sc.parallelize(['id1,pd1,t1,5.0', 'id2,pd2,t2,6.0', 'id1,pd1,t2,7.5', 'id1,pd1,t3,8.1'])
rdd = lines.map(lambda x: x.split(',')).map(lambda x: (x[0] + ', ' + x[1], x[3])).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + ', ' + b)
print rdd.collect()
```

Then you will get the transposed result.

```
[('id1, pd1', '5.0, 7.5, 8.1'), ('id2, pd2', '6.0')]
```

Comment: This is definitely an interesting way of solving this. I figured another way of achieving the same. But I guess, your method might be much faster than mine. I am sharing my own solution as well.

Comment: Does PySpark not have `groupByKey`?

Comment: PySpark has the method [groupBykey](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html). However, the question tends to group records together based on two fields, instead of doing aggregation such as `SELECT sum(value) FROM data GROUP BY id, pd`. So `groupBykey` may not help.

Answer (score 2):

I grouped ((id1,t1),((p1,5.0),(p2,6.0)) and so on ... as my map function. Later, I reduce using map_group which creates an array for [p1,p2,  . . . ] and fills in values in their respective positions.

```
def map_group(pgroup):
    x = np.zeros(19)
    x[0] = 1
    value_list = pgroup[1]
    for val in value_list:
        fno = val[0].split('.')[0]
        x[int(fno)-5] = val[1]
    return x

tgbr = tfile.map(lambda d: ((d[0][0],d[0][2]),[(d[0][1],d[1])])) \
                .reduceByKey(lambda p,q:p+q) \
                .map(lambda d: (d[0], map_group(d)))
```

This does feel like an expensive solution in terms of computation. But works for now.