# Spark: use reduceByKey instead of groupByKey and mapByValues

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an RDD with duplicates values with the following format:

```
[ {key1: A}, {key1: A}, {key1: B}, {key1: C}, {key2: B}, {key2: B}, {key2: D}, ..]
```

I would like the new RDD to have the following output and to get ride of duplicates.

```
[ {key1: [A,B,C]}, {key2: [B,D]}, ..]
```

I have manage to do this with the following code by putting the values in a set to get ride of duplicates.

```
RDD_unique = RDD_duplicates.groupByKey().mapValues(lambda x: set(x))
```

But I am trying to achieve this more elegantly in 1 command with

```
RDD_unique = RDD_duplicates.reduceByKey(...)
```

I have not managed to come up with a lambda function that gets me the same result in the reduceByKey function.

Comment: To remove the duplicate, have you tried https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#distinct  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```python
data = (sc.parallelize([ {key1: A}, {key1: A}, {key1: B},
  {key1: C}, {key2: B}, {key2: B}, {key2: D}, ..]))

result = (data
  .mapValues(lambda x: {x})
  .reduceByKey(lambda s1, s2: s1.union(s2)))
```