# How to group and add up in spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, distributed-computing, rdd

I have an RDD like this:

```
{"key1" : "fruit" , "key2" : "US" , "key3" : "1" }

{"key1" : "fruit" , "key2" : "US" , "key3" : "2" }

{"key1" : "vegetable" , "key2" : "US" , "key3" : "1" }

{"key1" : "fruit" , "key2" : "Japan" , "key3" : "3" }

{"key1" : "vegetable" , "key2" : "Japan" , "key3" : "3" }
```

My goal is to 
first group by **key1** and then group by **key2** 
and finally add **key3**.

I am expecting final result like,

```
key1          key2      key3
"fruit"     , "US"    , 3
"vegetable" , "US"    , 1
"fruit"     , "Japan" , 3
"vegetable" , "Japan" , 3
```

My code begins as below ,

```
rdd_arm = rdd_arm.map(lambda x: x[1])
```

rdd_arm includes the above key : value format.

I am not sure where to go next.
Could some one help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create your RDD:

```
In [1]: rdd_arm = sc.parallelize([{"key1" : "fruit" , "key2" : "US" , "key3" : "1" }, {"key1" : "fruit" , "key2" : "US" , "key3" : "2" }, {"key1" : "vegetable" , "key2" : "US" ,  "key3" : "1" }, {"key1" : "fruit" , "key2" : "Japan" , "key3" : "3" }, {"key1" : "vegetable" , "key2" : "Japan" , "key3" : "3" }])
In [2]: rdd_arm.collect()
Out[2]: 
[{'key1': 'fruit', 'key2': 'US', 'key3': '1'},
 {'key1': 'fruit', 'key2': 'US', 'key3': '2'},
 {'key1': 'vegetable', 'key2': 'US', 'key3': '1'},
 {'key1': 'fruit', 'key2': 'Japan', 'key3': '3'},
 {'key1': 'vegetable', 'key2': 'Japan', 'key3': '3'}]
```

First, you have to create a new key, which will be the pair of `key1` and `key2`. The value of it will be `key3`, so you want to do something like this:

```
In [3]: new_rdd = rdd_arm.map(lambda x: (x['key1'] + ", " + x['key2'], x['key3']))

In [4]: new_rdd.collect()
Out[4]: 
[('fruit, US', '1'),
 ('fruit, US', '2'),
 ('vegetable, US', '1'),
 ('fruit, Japan', '3'),
 ('vegetable, Japan', '3')]
```

Then, we want to add the values of the keys that are duplicates, simply be calling [reduceByKey()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=reducebykey#pyspark.RDD.reduceByKey), like this:

```
In [5]: new_rdd = new_rdd.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: int(a) + int(b))

In [6]: new_rdd.collect()
Out[6]: 
[('fruit, US', 3),
 ('fruit, Japan', '3'),
 ('vegetable, US', '1'),
 ('vegetable, Japan', '3')]
```

and we are done!

---

Of course, this could be one-liner, like this:

```
new_rdd = rdd_arm.map(lambda x: (x['key1'] + ", " + x['key2'], x['key3'])).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: int(a) + int(b))
```

Comment: Hello gsamaras . Thank you for the follow up.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it myself.

I had to create a key including multiple keys and then add up.

```
rdd_arm.map( lambda x : x[0] + ", " + x[1] , x[2] ).reduceByKey( lambda a,b : a + b )
```

Below question was useful.

[How to group by multiple keys in spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372792/how-to-group-by-multiple-keys-in-spark)

Comment: Allow me to say that this didn't work for me, I was getting errors of undefined name, and after getting getting by them, I was not able to make it work. As a result I posted a new answer, hope you like it! I upvoted the question though, since it made me practice! Thanks!